# Kendo().ComboBox does not retain selected values when inside of a Kendo().Grid's Editor Template when moving the focus away from the row

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I've been struggling with that for a while and cannot figure out the solution.

When display `Kendo().ComboBox` inside of a `Kendo().Grid`, it is populated with the data.

However, when changing the value inside of the `ComboBox` or Adding a new Record to the Grid, the value does not remain the same when switching the focus from the current row.

*Before change:*
[image]

*After change and switching focus:*
New Value:
[image]

*After switching focus:*
[image]

In case of changing it to the new value, it defaults to the old one.
And in case of adding a new record, it appears to be empty:

*When "ADD NEW RECORD" is clicked:*
[image]

*After switching focus:*
[image]

This is the logic I have:

**Controller:**

Populating Grid:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditingCustom_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<TestTicketReportPropertyModel> models, int ticketID)
{
    var ticketReportProp = new TestTicketReportPropertyModel().GetAll(ticketID);
    return Json(ticketReportProp.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Populating ComboBox:

```
public ActionResult PopulateReportProperty(int reportID)
{
    List<eBalance.Site.eBalanceServiceReference.ReportPropertyEntity> reportPropertyList = TicketReportPropertyRepository.GetReportPropertyEntityRepository(reportID);
    return Json(reportPropertyList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Model:**

```
//Getting Grid's data
public IList<TicketReportPropertyEntity> GetAll(int ticketID)
    => EBalanceService.GetTicketReportPropertyData(ticketID).ToList();
```

**Service method to get the data for the Grid:**

```
public List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> GetTicketReportPropertyData(int ticketId)
{
    var ticketReportPropertyData = TicketReportProperty.GetTicketReportPropertyData(ticketId);

    ticketReportPropertyData.ForEach(t => t.PropertyName = t.ReportProperty?.PropertyName ?? "0");
    ticketReportPropertyData.ForEach(t => t.ReportPropertyID = t.ReportProperty?.ReportPropertyID ?? 0);

    return ticketReportPropertyData;
}
```

**The View:**

```
<div class="div-table-row col-lg-12">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TicketReportPropertyEntity>()
            .Name("grid2")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden();
                columns.Bound(p =>p.PropertyName).EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Sortable(false).Width(400);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Amount).Width(130);
                columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
            })
            //.Events(events => events.Edit("Edit"))
              .ToolBar(toolBar =>
              {
                  toolBar.Create();
                  toolBar.Save();
              })
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(r => r.ID);
                })
                .PageSize(20)
                .Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "TestTicketReportProperty", new { ticketID = Model.TicketID }))
                .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "TestTicketReportProperty"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "TestTicketReportProperty"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "TestTicketReportProperty"))
                )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Editor Template:**

```
<script>
    function GetReportID() {
        return {
            reportID: $('#ReportID').attr('text'),
        };
    }

</script>

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                            .Name("ReportPropertyCB")
                            .DataValueField("ID")
                            .DataTextField("PropertyName")
                            //.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["reportProperties"])
                            .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("PopulateReportProperty", "TestTicketReportProperty").Data("GetReportID()")))
                            .Template("<span class=\"k-state-default\"><h3>#: PropertyName #</h3><p>#: ReportGroup #</p></span>")
                            )
```

I also tried to use the `Telerik's team` example and it did not work in my case.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For data-binding from grid to editor, the name of the editor should be the same as the name of the property. You can see more about [Create Custom Editors for Bound Properties](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates)
and [Value binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value).